# Normalize and denormalized arithmetic

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I have two numbers in similar standard like IEEE754 (1 for sign, 8 for exponent, 7 for multiplier), first is denormalized and second one is normalized. How can I add/divide them?

```
S     E       M               decimal    binary
0 00000000 1100000          = 2^(-127) * 0,1100000
0 11000000 0000001          = 2^65     * 1,0000001

BIAS = 2^(8-1)-1 = 127
```

Comment: Normalize the subnormal, then divide/add.

Comment: I thought about this, but how can I do that?

Comment: nothing special about a denormal.  to add you have to line up the decimal point, divide you dont but have to keep track of the exponent.  again no different than without denormals.

Comment: Okey, but I can't write exponent like 2^(-127-65) in this standard.

Comment: @ulou: I don't know what your context is, but in hardware implementation as well as in floating-point emulation, exponents typically use at least one additional bit compared to the (IEEE-754) storage format to allow for normalization of subnormals. Similarly, the implicit integer bit of the IEEE-754 format's mantissa (significand) is usually explicit in the internal representation.

Comment: Thanks, its enough for me. I have exam tomorrow and i might have exercise like this. I wanted to understand how can I handle this on paper.

Comment: @ulou If this occurs in an exam question, it is exceedingly likely that it was covered in class previously; check your notes.